# yaml parser error at Rstudio startup

Tags: r, rstudio

When I launch RStudio I see the following error. When I launch base R from the command line I do not see this error. I've updated all packages through base R, not RStudio.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1did not 
find expected key at line 7, column 1
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1did not 
find expected key at line 7, column 1
```

---

Here is some additional information

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.5 
tools_3.3.3     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.10    stringi_1.1.3  
[9] rmarkdown_1.3   knitr_1.15.1    stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.12   
evaluate_0.10
```

Comment: Presumedly, you have an R Markdown document open with an invalid YAML header. Could that be the case?

Comment: No, but this lead me to the solution. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin Ushey for the tip. I was working in an RStudio project and while it wasn't open, my _site.yml file did not have the correct format. My barebones _site.yml is copy-pasted below. My file used tabs to indent, below I've used two spaces to indicate a tab.

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "My Website"
    left:
      - text: "Home"
        href: index.html
      - text: "About"
        href: about.html
output_dir: "."
```